# Error in streaming a video from HTTPS url

Tags: android, video, https, streaming

I have no problem in streaming a video in a normal http. 
(example : http://www.mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4)

But when i change it into HTTPS. I have encounter an error
(example : https://www.mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4)

Does anyone have tried this? Streaming a video with HTTPS link to a 3rd party APP. (asking a user which app will be use to play video, by passing the url/uri to the app in android)

The current scenario is:

1.) I have a link which is https

2.) I have start an intent , and check all available video player installed in android phone ( i have currently installed vlc , mx
    player , videoplayer, built in OS player and others).

3.) I try to choose any of those above but none of them works. ( it just prompt a message, saying "Player encounter an Error" which is a
    generic error. Im just trying to pass the URL / URI to the player).

4.) Please take note, if i try to play it in the web browser everything works fine.

5.) Please take note that again , I was able to stream http video, using same piece of code

```
String videoURL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoURL));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoURL), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

In my manifest file, im using the default, except that i give permission to the internet.

Im not sure if this is related or this can help but : I was able to buffer a HTTPS Audio FILE coming from same SERVER. Since android has a built in media player that supports wav & mp3, im not asking the user to choose a media player, since it can support the above format. When i buffer the audio in the same server, i just issue below code. So everyting works well.

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

`

But when it comes to playing video, im asking the user which APP he wants to play, cause the file might not be supported.

**FIX**

**It looks like , android has some problem in broken chain certificates, in order to fix this, you must fix your broken chain certificate. To check your certificate, simply go to ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yourwebsite.com**

Comment: I've just tried this, and it works fine for me. Is that _your_ server you're streaming off? Maybe something wrong with the ssl certs? Can you try some of the samples on a public server like https://samples.mplayerhq.hu/ to see if it works. With regards to point 4 is this a web browser on your android device or your pc?

Comment: @ci_ im trying to play it on my android phone browser and it works, i have tried it to play in my desktop browser and it works also. Anything needed to be add in manifest?

Comment: I don't think so, I've just pasted your 4 lines of code into a dummy activity and it works fine for me, using https://samples.mplayerhq.hu/Matroska/multiple_tracks.mkv for example.

Comment: @ci_ assuming it can be played in the public server, but it cannot be played in our server (which i copy & downloaded same file from the private server and upload it to our server). What do you think is the problem?

Comment: I can only guess here. Maybe there's something wrong with your SSL certs. There might have been a warning at some stage in your browser that the connection is insecure and you accepted it and moved on, and now you get no more warnings, but your video player might stall on it.

Answer (score 2):

**After long struggle i found solution,**

> Override your videoview class and below code.

```
 @Override
public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setVideoURI(uri);
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);
        MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        sf.fixHttpsURLConnection();
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: :) Perfect answer