# How should I use @override set.videoUri(uri) in android java class?

Tags: android, ssl, video-streaming

I wanna stream from an https url and I found a solution that gives the below solution;

```
@Override
public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setVideoURI(uri);
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);
        MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        sf.fixHttpsURLConnection();
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the question is how should I use it in my java class?

Comment: I assume that `ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` disables hostname verification. If so, and if you plan on shipping via the Play Store, do not use this code, as it will cause your app to get banned.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, for now I'm just testing my app on a self-signed certificate. So it's ok. Do you have an alternative solution for streaming from an https url?

Comment: For testing, why not just use plain HTTP, then?

Comment: Cause I have to learn how to stream from HTTPS URLs and I face with no problem when streaming from HTTP URLs.

Comment: Then why not use a real SSL certificate, rather than a self-signed one?

Comment: As there is no need at this stage of developing my app but you're right finally I have to add it, I just want to give it a try. Unfortunately, I found no complete answer. It seems no one streams videos or audios through HTTPS. But I would be happy If I can put one complete guide here through your and other developers' help.

Comment: This is where I found the aforementioned solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966208/error-in-streaming-a-video-from-https-url?rq=1

Comment: "It seems no one streams videos or audios through HTTPS" -- sure they do. https://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4 works just fine in `VideoView`, for example, and `VideoView` uses `MediaPlayer`. I just tested it now on a Pixel C running Android 8.1. Your problem is that you are using a self-signed certificate, rather than a one from a recognized SSL certificate authority.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, you're right if it's implemented based on non self-signed certificate. But if you google self-signed ones you see that some can be streamed and some cannot. I can stream my own self-signed site's HTTPS URLs(mp4 files) but not all of them. I think there is a problem which I cannot handle well.